# Hiding cells within a table in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I figured out how to reference and hide a set of rows within a table in MS word.  However, is there a way to hide a single cell.  Below is my code for hiding rows:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim BBGEarlyAppr As Range
   Dim BBGEarlyAppr2 As Range
      With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
          Set BBGEarlyAppr = .Rows(7).Range
          BBGEarlyAppr.End = .Rows(41).Range.End
      End With

      With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
          Set BBGEarlyAppr2 = .Rows(60).Range
          BBGEarlyAppr2.End = .Rows(68).Range.End
       End With

      With BBGEarlyAppr.Font
           .Hidden = True
      End With
      With BBGEarlyAppr2.Font
          .Hidden = True
      End With
  End Sub
```

Comment: Would `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(60, 1).Range.Font.Hidden = True` work for you?

Comment: @Variatus IT WORKED WONDERFULLY! THANK YOU!